# How do I *save* the results of an angular material modal dialog?

Tags: angular, angular-material, modal-dialog

I have a component which opens a modal dialog to let the user input two dates. I would then like to save those two dates to a db model behind the component, but I am having trouble wrapping my head around when and where to obtain those results.

To be clear: I can currently see the dialog result as two dates in my main component's template, but I would like to know, in...some method...in my main component, when the dialog is closed and the dates are no longer nulls -- so I can save them to the DB.

My main component template has a button with an onClick event:

```
<a class="btn btn-sm role="button"><mat-icon title="Get Dates" (click)="onClickGetDates(appt)">flag</mat-icon></a> Result from dialog: {{ dateRangeArray }}
```

The main component implements the onClick event:

```
onClickGetDates(appt) {
    this.dialogService
      .confirmDateRange('Get Dates', 'Enter two dates:',
        appt.beginDate, appt.endDate)
      .subscribe(res => this.dateRange = res);
.
.
// I would like to now save the dateRange result to my database, but at this point, result is [null,null], so the code below does nothing (except null out the dates):
appt.beginDate = dateRange[0];
appt.endDate = dateRange[1];
this.apptdata.updateAppt(appt);
}
```

Here is confirmDateRange, defined in a Dialog Service, which actually displays the dialog:

```
public confirmDateRange(title: string, message: string, begin: Date, end: Date): Observable<boolean> {
    let dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ConfirmDialogComponent>;

    dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmDialogComponent);
    dialogRef.componentInstance.title = title;
    dialogRef.componentInstance.message = message;
    dialogRef.componentInstance.beginDate = begin;
    dialogRef.componentInstance.endDate = end;

    return dialogRef.afterClosed();
  }
```

And the dialog component:

```
export class ConfirmDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  public title: string;
  public message: string;

  public beginDate: Date;
  public endDate: Date;

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ConfirmDialogComponent>) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

And the dialog's template:

```
<h2>{{ title }}</h2>
<hr>
<p>{{ message }}</p>

<!--Date Picker Begin-->

<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="beginDatePicker" placeholder="Beginning" [(ngModel)]="beginDate">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="beginDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #beginDatePicker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>


<!--Date Picker End-->

<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="endDatePicker" placeholder="Ending" [(ngModel)]="endDate">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="endDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #endDatePicker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>


<!--OK-->
<button type="button" mat-raised-button
        (click)="dialogRef.close([beginDate, endDate])">OK</button>

<!--Cancel-->
<button type="button" mat-button
        (click)="dialogRef.close()">Cancel</button>
```

After clicking OK in the dialog, I can see the resultant array with the two dates in the main component's template like this: `Result from dialog: {{ dateRangeArray }}`. Trying to access the same result in onClickGetDates is 'too soon' and the result is a null array...So, where/when is the proper place to see that result in my main component?

I feel like I'm mis-using the dialog's AfterClose() event, and that I should be able to retrieve results just after that event is fired, but I'm still too green with Angular to realize what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Firstly, I strongly advise that you shouldn't mix Bootstrap with Angular Material as the styles may conflict with each other. Secondly, `MatDialogRef#afterClosed` returns an observable with the result of the value specified via the `matDialogClose` attribute in your component's template or via `MatDialogRef#close`, which allows for an optional result argument to be specified.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
onClickGetDates(appt) {
    this.dialogService
      .confirmDateRange('Get Dates', 'Enter two dates:',
        appt.beginDate, appt.endDate)
      .subscribe(res => 
      {this.dateRange = res;
//Set the appt's properties inside the subscribe
appt.beginDate = this.dateRange[0];
appt.endDate = this.dateRange[1];
this.apptdata.updateAppt(appt);
});
```

Comment: That is exactly my code, but you have changed a comment. What did you intend for me to do differently?

Comment: @John Marquez No it's not. Like indicated by that comment, the variables'assignment is INSIDE the subscribe callback. In your code, they are AFTER.

Answer (score 0):

```
                Use @Output() to send dates from inner component to outer component and implement a function that call on Ok button and emit that data from that function like : 
                `@Output() response =  new EventEmitter()<any>;

                onOkClicked()
                {
                this.response.next({beginDate : beginDate , endDate: endDate});
                this.dialogRef.close();
                }

                onCancelClicked()
                {
                this.dialogRef.close();
                }

                confirmDateRange(title: string, message: string,appt): Observable<boolean> {
                let dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ConfirmDialogComponent>;

                dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmDialogComponent);
                dialogRef.componentInstance.title = title;
                dialogRef.componentInstance.message = message;
                dialogRef.componentInstance.beginDate = appt.begin;
                dialogRef.componentInstance.endDate = appt.end;
                dialogRef.componentInstance.response.subscribe(res : any => {
                appt.begin = res.beginDate;
                appt.end = res.endDate;
                });

              }

           onClickGetDates(title:string , message :string , appt) {
           this.confirmDateRange(title,message,appt);
            }
                `
```

Comment: I see how this subscribes to the result of the dialog in the dialog's service, but how does this get the result back to my main component, where I want to save it to the DB?